# Could not load file or assembly 'PayPalCoreSDK'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, web-applications, .net-assembly

I have 2 webapp projects that work perfectly with this assembly.

I've tried everything, copy the BIN folder, delete, make a rebuild.

Search for things in the GAC, remove and add references again, with NUGET without NUGET, copy from the folder of projects that work.

My error was that on the first try I added the reference through the nuget manager rather than simply copying the DLLs from the projects that work

Now there is something causing version error.

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'PayPalCoreSDK, Version = 1.7.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 5b4afc1ccaef40fb' or one of its dependencies. The localized assembly manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

How to clear this mess and fix those references?

Everything is the same as the other 2 projects that work, even code, even web.config.

I do not know where else to look for solutions.

PayPalMerchantSDK (2.16.204.0)

Dependencies: PayPalCoreSDK (1.7.1.0) - Newtonsoft.Json (9.0.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the .net framework version in same as your other 2 projects?

Comment: Yes, is the same. asp.NET 4.5, all codes, all DLLs are the same, same web.config code too.

Comment: I search for all aspects that can be different, but all is the same, i think that the problem is outside of visual studio.

Comment: Did you try with delete OBJ folder?

Comment: Where is the obj folder ? I think im in a website and not has a obj folder.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts I managed to make the project work.

However, I had to work with older versions of PayPalCoreSDK and Newtonsof.Json.

Now I will try to adjust the versions to see if I can align all the projects.

But the references are confusing and if it gives problem it seems that only NUGET can refresh DLLs properly

Manual settings in the BIN folder do not work much less in web.config.

Comment: can you please tell me which versions of both PayPalCoreSDK and Newtonsof.Json worked?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this error as well. I was able to fix it by just downgrading the version of the PaypalCoreSDK to the previous one.